# Querying Big Query Table using javascript POST method

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

Hi I am new to google biqquery , so i want to make a POST method request to query big query table i am not aware where to pass the Query in the request so please help.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to issue a query, but the short version is:

- Get an OAuth access token (generally by using the gapi client).
- Insert a query job.
- Monitor for completion (a job may take a while to run, so you generally need to poll its status with a jobs.get operation).
- Retrieve the results from the temporary table.

Inserting a query job can be done through this endpoint:

`POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/queries`

The various REST endpoints are described in the public documentation here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query#http-request

While you didn't describe your reason for doing this, I'll mention that consuming BigQuery directly is probably not something you want to do from a multi-user website (because each user would need to be a member of your project). You may be better off issuing queries and caching the results on the backend and providing your own frontend to render the results.

Comment: i am trying to create a google chrome extension, using that extension i want to display the big query table data

Comment: so i need to know how to send query in post method